# numpy where takes at most 3 arguments - a way around this?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

def myf(c):
    return c*11

def method_A(c):
    return c*999

def method_B(c):
    return c*55

minimum = 30
maximum = 100
the_method = 'A'

b = np.array([1, 20, 35, 3, 45, 52, 78, 101, 127, 135])
```

I want to use numpy where in order to fulfill some conditions.

Something like:

```
b = np.where( np.logical_or(b < minimum , b > maximum) , b, 
             (if the_method == 'A': method_A(b)) ,
             (if the_method == 'B': method_B(b)))
```

If the conditions `b < min or b > max` are met, leave each element in b as it is, else, `if the_method is A , call method A` else `if method is B, call method B`

So , I tried :

```
b = np.where( np.logical_or(b < minimum , b > maximum) , b, 
             (np.where(the_method == 'A',method_A(b),b)),
             (np.where(the_method == 'B',method_B(b),b))
            )
```

which gives me `function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)` because np.where can't accept more than 3 arguments.

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: Are you needing additional parentheses around the inner `where`? like this: `In [20]:

b = np.where( np.logical_or(b < minimum , b > maximum) , b, 
             ((np.where(the_method == 'A',method_A(b),b)),
             (np.where(the_method == 'B',method_B(b),b)))
            )
b
Out[20]:
array([[    1,    20, 34965,     3, 44955, 51948, 77922,   101,   127,
          135],
       [    1,    20,    35,     3,    45,    52,    78,   101,   127,
          135]])`?

Comment: Hmm..Yes! I just want one array as output, not two.

Comment: `np.where` with its three args implements IF-ELSE, whereas you have two IFs. So, I am not sure if `np.where` is a good choice here.

Comment: @EdChum:Hm, ok! I just open the parenthesis and use `((np.where(apply_method == 'A',method_A(b),
             (np.where(apply_method == 'B',method_B(b),None))` and it works fine!If you want make it an answer, thanks

Comment: Your posted snippet doesn't work, `apply_method` is not defined

Comment: @EdChum: I meant `the_method`, sorry

Comment: that returns a 3-d array with shape (2,2,10) using this `np.where(the_method == 'A',method_A(b), (np.where(the_method == 'B',method_B(b),None)))` is that what you want?

Comment: @EdChum:[Here](http://pastebin.com/ESk0kDFA) is the code.It gives shape 10,

Comment: Ah OK, I'll post an answer just so this question is answered, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses were not balanced, you needed additional parentheses in the inner condition:

```
In [33]:
b = np.where( np.logical_or(b < minimum , b > maximum) , b,
             ((np.where(apply_method == 'A',method_A(b),
             (np.where(apply_method == 'B',method_B(b),None))
            ))))
b

Out[33]:
array([1, 20, 35000, 3, 45000, 52000, 78000, 101, 127, 135], dtype=object)
```

Your initial attempt:

```
b = np.where( np.logical_or(b < minimum , b > maximum) , b, 
             (np.where(the_method == 'A',method_A(b),b)),
             (np.where(the_method == 'B',method_B(b),b))
            )
```

needed parentheses on the *other* condition

Comment: Watch out for the performance cost that threatening to insert `None` has created here - the array is now `dtype=object`

Answer (score 3):

`the_method` is a scalar not an array, so you don't need the inner `np.where`s here:

```
if the_method == 'A':
    which_method = method_A 
elif the_method == 'B':
    which_method = method_B 
else:
    raise ValueError

b = np.where(
    (b < minimum) | (b > maximum),
     b, 
     which_method(b)
)
```

In fact, if you insert a `print` in both methods, you'll see than when using `np.where`, they both run.

If you're really set on getting that in one expression:

```
def _raise(x): raise x

b = np.where(
    (b < minimum) | (b > maximum),
     b, 
     (
         method_A if the_method == 'A' else
         method_B if the_method == 'B' else
         _raise(ValueError)
     )(b)
)
```